# Does Dirac's theorem on Hamiltonian cycles only apply to undirected graphs?

Tags: graph-theory

Does [Dirac's theorem on Hamiltonian cycles](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac%27s_theorem) only apply for undirected graphs? If the theorem applied to directed graphs, the graph with the following adjacency list should have a Hamiltonian cycle, but I can't find one.

> $0$: $1$ $2$ $3$
>
> $1$: $2$ $3$
>
> $2$: $1$ $3$
>
> $3$: $1$ $2$

Comment: Yes Dirac Theorem is for undirected graphs, directed variation is this(is not by dirac): If $G$ is a strongly connected graph and $\delta^+(G)+\delta^-(G) \ge n$. $\delta^+(G)$ is minimum out degree and $\delta^-(G)$ is minimum in degree of $G$.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While Dirac's theorem wasn't intended/proved for directed graphs, it was extended to directed graphs by GHOUILA-HOURI in 1960 ("Une condition suffisante d’existence d'un circuit hamiltonien").

Their requirements, however, were that each vertex should have both out-degree **and in-degree** of at least $n/2$, which is not the case in your graph.

One of the original conditions of GHOUILA-HOURI, as Saeed mentioned, is that the graph is strongly connected. In fact, the degree conditions [are strong enough](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22247/does-deltag-delta-g-geq-n-imply-strong-connectivity/22299#22299) for only diameter $\leq 2$ graphs to be considered.